# Which is better: "was to become" versus "would become"?

Tags: word-usage

> ... where she filmed what was to become her final performance ...

OR

> ... where she filmed what would become her final performance ...

(I like the first one, as it seems to (accurately) imply that it was fully unknown that it would become her final performance... )

Comment: If you're only asking which is the preferred option, that's really not on topic here as it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Personally, I would say, "where she filmed what was to **be** her final performance."

Comment: Sounds like you're writing an article about either Debbie Reynolds or Carrie Fisher. Sad :/.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there is much difference, but to me:

> ...where she filmed what **was to become** her final performance ...

talks about a definite occurrence in the past, while

> ... where she filmed **what would become** her final performance ...

also talks about the past, but from a reported time just before her final performance.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Catija 's comment:  Both are fine, and have more or less the same meaning.  Both indicate that was, *definitely* her final performance.  Both imply that no one knew it would be her final performance.

Which you use depends more on context and personal style. The first is somewhat more *dramatic*.

(Note: to avoid the vote to close this question as off-topic, I would change the question to ask about the difference between the two, instead of which is "better")